# Return an array from axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-resource

I'm working on computed properties of Vue.js

There is a computed method which requests an axios api to get an array(after performed some logics inside the promise).

```
computed: {
    filteredTrips: function () {
        var filtered = this.trips;
        if(this.filters_by.indexOf('monitor')>=0) filtered = this.filter(filtered, this.BusMonitorID,'BusMonitorID');
        if(this.filters_by.indexOf('route')>=0) filtered =  this.filter(filtered,  this.TourID,'TourID');
        if(this.filtered_count==0) return this.getFilteredTrips(); //This is the axios method to get an array
        return filtered;
    }
},
methods: {
    getFilteredTrips:function(){
      var resource = base_url+'report/transport/filter';
      var self = this;
      axios.post(resource, $.param({filters:this.filters})).then(function(response) {
        // here i'm performing some logics to make self.trips

        self.trips.push(data[trip]); //push data to self.trips

        return self.trips; // i need to return this array
      }).catch(function(response) {
            // error callback
        })
     }
}
```

The problem is `getFilteredTrips()` not return self.trips array,
 How to make it as possible through axios/js?

Answer (score 0):

computed property can not have asynchronous tasks like making a backend call, you should use methods instead of computed property to  call this method: `getFilteredTrips`.

You can have a data: `filteredTrips`, which you can update in the `getFilteredTrips` function.  You code should look like something:

```
data:{
  return {
    filteredTrips: []
  }
},
computed: {
    filteredTripsComputed: function () {
        var filtered = this.trips;
        if(this.filters_by.indexOf('monitor')>=0) filtered = this.filter(filtered, this.BusMonitorID,'BusMonitorID');
        if(this.filters_by.indexOf('route')>=0) filtered =  this.filter(filtered,  this.TourID,'TourID');
        return filtered;
    }
},
methods: {
    filteredTrips:function(){
        if(this.filtered_count==0) return this.getFilteredTrips(); 
         return this.filteredTripsComputed;
    }
    getFilteredTrips:function(){
      var resource = base_url+'report/transport/filter';
      var self = this;
      axios.post(resource, $.param({filters:this.filters})).then(function(response) {
        // here i'm performing some logics to make self.trips

        self.trips.push(data[trip]); //push data to self.trips

        self.filteredTrips = self.trips; // i need to return this array
      }).catch(function(response) {
            // error callback
        })
     }
}
```

Comment: I need the computed property there because i'm looping reactive data of self.trips on page.
something like  <div class="list-group-item" v-for="trip in filteredTrips"> this.

Comment: Well, Why i'm using computed property here is i'm doing client side filtering of same data. you can see my edited code above.

Comment: @user3391137 You can not call an async method from computed property, if that is need, you have to use method.

Comment: As you can see, I need something like computed property to acheive this with client side filtering. I hope in this case we cannot use the method.Do you have any other idea to accomplish it?

Comment: @user3391137 You can use method, you can use same code in a method, in-fact this will work only in method, see my update, with a combined approach for your case.

Comment: How to call  filteredTripsComputed() ?

Comment: @user3391137 You do just this: `this,filteredTripsComputed`

Comment: I mean, on page we call <div class="list-group-item" v-for="trip in filteredTrips">.So then how to invoke the "filteredTripsComputed" on "filteredTrips" changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138249/discussion-between-saurabh-and-user3391137).